# ActiveSupport::Inflector::camelize - help in understanding regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, activesupport

### Short version:

I am having a rather hard time understanding two rather complex regular expressions in the `ActiveSupport::Inflector::camelize` method.

This is the definition of the `camelize` method:

```
def camelize(term, uppercase_first_letter = true)
  string = term.to_s
  if uppercase_first_letter
    string = string.sub(/^[a-z\d]*/) { inflections.acronyms[$&] || $&.capitalize }
  else
    string = string.sub(/^(?:#{inflections.acronym_regex}(?=\b|[A-Z_])|\w)/) { $&.downcase }
  end
  string.gsub(/(?:_|(\/))([a-z\d]*)/i) { "#{$1}#{inflections.acronyms[$2] || $2.capitalize}" }.gsub('/', '::')
end
```

I have some difficulty understanding:

```
string = string.sub(/^(?:#{inflections.acronym_regex}(?=\b|[A-Z_])|\w)/) { $&.downcase }
```

and:

```
string.gsub(/(?:_|(\/))([a-z\d]*)/i) { "#{$1}#{inflections.acronyms[$2] || $2.capitalize}" }.gsub('/', '::')
```

Please explain to me what they mean. Thank you.

## Long version

This shows me trying to understand the regex and how I interpret them to mean. It would be very helpful if you could go through this and correct my mistakes.

### For the first regex

```
string = string.sub(/^(?:#{inflections.acronym_regex}(?=\b|[A-Z_])|\w)/) { $&.downcase }
```

Based on what I am seeing, `inflections.acronym_regex` is from the `Inflections` class in the `ActiveSupport::Inflector` module, and in the `initialize` method of the `Inflections` class,

```
def initialize
  @plurals, @singulars, @uncountables, @humans, @acronyms, @acronym_regex = [], [], [], [], {}, /(?=a)b/
end
```

`acronym_regex` is assigned `/(?=a)b/`. From what I understand from http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors ,

```
(?=pat) - Positive lookahead assertion: ensures that the following characters match pat, but doesn't include those characters in the matched text
```

So `/(?=a)b/` ensures that character `a` is inside the text, but we dont include character `a` inside the matched text, and what immediately follows character `a` must be character `b`. In other words, `"abc"` would match this regex, but `"bbc"` would not match this regex, and the matched text for `"abc"` would be `"b"` (instead of `"ab"`).

So combining the value of `inflections.acronym_regex` into this regex `/^(?:#{inflections.acronym_regex}(?=\b|[A-Z_])|\w)/`, I do not know which of the following two regex results:

A. `/^(?:/(?=a)b/(?=\b|[A-Z_])|\w)/`

B. `/^(?:(?=a)b(?=\b|[A-Z_])|\w)/`

although I am thinking it is B. From what I understand, `(?:` provides grouping without capturing, `(?=` means positive lookahead assertion, `\b` matches word boundaries when outside brackets and matches backspace when inside brackets. So in english terms, regex B, when matching against a text, will find a string that begins with an `a` character, followed by a `b` character, and one of (1. backspace [whatever that may mean] 2. any uppercase character or underscore 3. any english alphabetic character, digit, or underscore).

However, I find it strange that passing `upper_case_first_letter = false` to the `camelize` function should cause it to match a string starting with the characters `ab`, given that that does not seem to be how the `camelize` function behaves.

### For the second regex

```
string.gsub(/(?:_|(\/))([a-z\d]*)/i) { "#{$1}#{inflections.acronyms[$2] || $2.capitalize}" }.gsub('/', '::')
```

The regex is:

```
/(?:_|(\/))([a-z\d]*)/i
```

I am guessing that this regex will match a substring that starts with either an `_` or `/`, followed by 0 or more (upper or lowercase english alpabetic characters or digit). Furthermore, for the first group `(?:_|(\/))`, whether we match the `_` or `/`, the `([a-z\d]*)` capturing group will always be regarded as the second group. I do understand the part where the block tries to look up `inflections.acronyms[$2]` and on failure, does `$2.captitalize`.

Since `(?:` means grouping without capturing, what is the value of `$1` when we match `_` ? Is it still `_` ? And for the `.gsub('/', '::')` portion, I am guessing that it gets applied for each match in the initial `gsub`, instead of being applied to the overall string after the outer `gsub` call is done?

Apologies for the really long post. Please point out my errors in understanding the 2 regular expressions, or explain them in a better way if you can do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please make your question concise.

Comment: @sawa, I could edit it such that it becomes very concise, but then would that help people who view the question in seeing where my difficulty lies in understanding the 2 regex? I think not.

Comment: In any case I think I will add a tldr section.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I find it strange that passing upper_case_first_letter =
>   false to the camelize function should cause it to match a string
>   starting with the characters ab, given that that does not seem to be
>   how the camelize function behaves.

`?:` acts like a `.` here and does match the string (ie. single character) but there is no grouping, therefore the match is in `$&`.

> Since (?: means grouping without capturing, what is the value of $1
>   when we match _ ? Is it still _ ?

It's `nil` since there is no capturing. The value is in `$2`

> And for the .gsub('/', '::') portion, I am guessing that it gets
>   applied for each match in the initial gsub, instead of being applied
>   to the overall string after the outer gsub call is done?

It's applied to the overall result as `gsub` with block returns a string and the `gsub('/', '::')` is outside of a block.